# Efficient method for imposing (some cases of) periodic boundary conditions on floats?

Tags: math, graphics, floating-point, ieee-754

Some cases of [periodic boundary conditions (PBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions) can be imposed very efficiently on integers by simply doing:

```
myWrappedWithinPeriodicBoundary = myUIntValue & mask
```

This works when the boundary is the half open range [0, upperBound), where the (exclusive) upperBound is 2^exp so that

```
mask = (1 << exp) - 1
```

For example:

```
let pbcUpperBoundExp = 2 // so the periodic boundary will be [0, 4)
let mask = (1 << pbcUpperBoundExp) - 1
for x in -7 ... 7 { print(x & mask, terminator: " ") }
```

(in Swift) will print:

```
1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
```

**Question:** Is there any (roughly similar) efficient method for imposing (some cases of) PBCs on floating point-numbers (32 or 64-bit IEEE-754)?

Comment: Interesting question. If Swift has an implementation of `fmod()` it might be best to use that, rather than trying to directly twiddle the bits. There are a lot of subtleties with float representations. I don't think that anything as simple as a bit mask on the mantissa part would be adequate.

Comment: `fmod` is about as good as you are going to get. It requires a division, which is typically a slow instruction. The result will be exact (introduce no new arithmetic error.) If you know the operand is less than one period outside the interval, then one or two compare and add or compare and subtract sequences might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasonable approaches:

1. [`fmod(x,1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod)
2. [`modf(x,&dummy)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf) — has the advantage of knowing its divisor statically, but in my testing comes from `libc.so.6` even with `-ffast-math`
3. [`x-floor(x)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor) (suggested by Jens in a comment) — supports negative inputs directly
4. Manual bit-twiddling direct implementation
5. Manual bit-twiddling implementation of `floor`

The first two preserve the sign of their input; you can add 1 if it's negative.

The two bit manipulations are very similar: you identify which significand bits correspond to the integer portion, and mask them (for the direct implementation) or the rest (to implement `floor`) off.  The direct implementation can be completed either with a floating-point division or with a shift to reassemble the `double` manually; the former is 28% faster even given hardware [CLZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set).  The `floor` implementation can immediately reconstitute a `double`: `floor` never changes the exponent of its argument unless it returns 0.  About 20 lines of C are required.

The following timing is with `double` and `gcc -O3`, with timing loops over representative inputs into which the operative code was inlined.

```
fmod: 41.8 ns
modf: 19.6 ns
floor: 10.6 ns
```

With -ffast-math:

```
fmod: 26.2 ns
modf: 30.0 ns
floor: 21.9 ns
```

Bit manipulation:

```
direct: 18.0 ns
floor: 20.6 ns
```

The manual implementations are competitive, but the `floor` technique is the best.  Oddly, two of the three library functions perform better without `-ffast-math`: that is, as a PLT function call than as an inlined builtin function.

Comment: Thanks for the great info! Especially the part about modf(x, &dummy) being faster than fmod(x, 1). As I'm not sure how to correctly interpret "97% faster" (almost twice as fast I guess?), I did some tests of my own and found that modf(x, &dummy) is about 6 times faster than fmod(x, 1) (which I have no idea how to correctly convert into percentages of speed).

Comment: @Jens: 97% faster means 1.97 times as fast (or 0.51 the run time, or 49% shorter run time).  I’m surprised by 6 times faster: maybe your `modf` was inlined somehow?

Comment: Also, for the unit range [0, 1), we can use (x - floor(x)) which according to my testing is a lot faster than modf(x, &dummy), and slightly faster than simd_fract(x). With added benefit that it works for negative numbers as is, always returning a value within [0, 1).

Comment: @Jens: I agree that `floor` is faster.  I feel silly for not thinking of it myself; I guess I was mostly thinking of methods that would work for any power of 2 as the range (like for integers).  Would you like me to update this answer, or shall we just promote yours?

Comment: @David: Please feel free to update this answer! For some reason I hadn't actually thought about floor either, until I wrote the above comment. I will update my answer with some info on simd float2.

Comment: @David See EDIT2 in my answer for a potential problem when using x - floor(x).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to my own question since it describes the, at the time of writing, best solution I have found. It's in Swift 4.1 (should be straight forward to translate into C) and it's been tested in various use cases:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    /// Returns the value after restricting it to the periodic boundary
    /// condition [0, 1).
    /// See https://forums.swift.org/t/why-no-fraction-in-floatingpoint/10337
    @_transparent
    func wrappedToUnitRange() -> Self {
        let fract = self - self.rounded(.down)
        // Have to clamp to just below 1 because very small negative values
        // will otherwise return an out of range result of 1.0.
        // Turns out this:
        if fract >= 1.0 { return Self(1).nextDown } else { return fract }
        // is faster than this:
        //return min(fract, Self(1).nextDown)
    }
    @_transparent
    func wrapped(to range: Range<Self>) -> Self {
        let measure = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
        let recipMeasure = Self(1) / measure
        let scaled = (self - range.lowerBound) * recipMeasure
        return scaled.wrappedToUnitRange() * measure + range.lowerBound
    }
    @_transparent
    func wrappedIteratively(to range: Range<Self>) -> Self {
        var v = self
        let measure = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
        while v >= range.upperBound { v = v - measure }
        while v < range.lowerBound { v = v + measure }
        return v
    }
}
```

On my MacBook Pro with a 2 GHz Intel Core i7, 
a hundred million (probably inlined) calls to `wrapped(to range:)` on random (finite) Double values takes 0.6 seconds, which is about 166 million calls per second (not multi threaded). The range being statically known or not, or having bounds or measure that is a power of two etc, can make some difference but not as much as one could perhaps have thought.

`wrappedToUnitRange()` takes about 0.2 seconds, meaning 500 million calls per second on my system.

Given the right scenario, `wrappedIteratively(to range:)` is as fast as `wrappedToUnitRange()`.

The timings have been made by comparing a baseline test (without wrapping some value, but still using it to compute eg a simple xor checksum) to the same test where a value is wrapped. The difference in time between these are the times I have given for the wrapping calls.

I have used Swift development toolchain 2018-02-21, compiling with -O -whole-module-optimization -static-stdlib -gnone. And care has been taken to make the tests relevant, ie preventing dead code removal, using true random input of different distributions etc. Writing the wrapping functions generically, like this extension on BinaryFloatingPoint, turned out to be optimized into equivalent code as if I had written separate specialized versions for eg  Float and Double.

It would be interesting to see someone more skilled than me investigating this further (C or Swift or any other language doesn't matter).

EDIT:
For anyone interested, here is some versions for simd float2:

```
extension float2 {
    @_transparent
    func wrappedInUnitRange() -> float2 {
        return simd.fract(self)
    }
    @_transparent
    func wrappedToMinusOneToOne() -> float2 {
        let scaled = (self + float2(1, 1)) * float2(0.5, 0.5)
        let scaledFract = scaled - floor(scaled)
        let wrapped = simd_muladd(scaledFract, float2(2, 2), float2(-1, -1))
        // Note that we have to make sure the result is not out of bounds, like
        // simd fract does:
        let oneNextDown = Float(bitPattern:
            0b0_01111110_11111111111111111111111)
        let oneNextDownFloat2 = float2(oneNextDown, oneNextDown)
        return simd.min(wrapped, oneNextDownFloat2)
    }
    @_transparent
    func wrapped(toLowerBound lowerBound: float2,
                 upperBound: float2) -> float2
    {
        let measure = upperBound - lowerBound
        let recipMeasure = simd_precise_recip(measure)
        let scaled = (self - lowerBound) * recipMeasure
        let scaledFract = scaled - floor(scaled)
        // Note that we have to make sure the result is not out of bounds, like
        // simd fract does:
        let wrapped = simd_muladd(scaledFract, measure, lowerBound)
        let maxX = upperBound.x.nextDown // For some reason, this won't be
        let maxY = upperBound.y.nextDown // optimized even when upperBound is
        // statically known, and there is no similar simd function available.
        let maxValue = float2(maxX, maxY)
        return simd.min(wrapped, maxValue)
    }
}
```

I asked some related simd-related questions [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/simd-performance-question/10285) which might be of interest.

EDIT2:

As can be seen in the above Swift Forums thread:

```
// Note that tiny negative values like:
let x: Float = -1e-08
// May produce results outside the [0, 1) range:
let wrapped = x - floor(x)
print(wrapped < 1.0) // false
// which may result in out-of-bounds table accesses
// in common usage, so it's probably better to use:
let correctlyWrapped = simd_fract(x)
print(correctlyWrapped < 1.0) // true
```

I have since updated the code to account for this.